# How can I send IP Camera output to a central server

Tags: router, ip-camera

I have a DLink DCS-934L IP Camera which I have in my local network. I can monitor the video on a browser and use it in a HTML program in my network. I would like to send the stream to a central server so I can monitor the stream remotely. DLink provides a service myDlink which allows this But I need to write an app as part of a home security project.

I have seen a similar question [Local/Public Access](https://superuser.com/questions/652191/how-to-locally-within-lan-and-publicly-over-internet-access-an-ip-camera-usi) but I have not understood the issue well enough.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to provide more information.  However, one solution that might work (if the camera can broadcast as an RTSP stream) is to run an [RTSP proxy](http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/) on the central server.  Point this proxy at the stream from the camera, and then you can access the stream from this server.